# react js Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React with Spring Boot.

When I try to get all values in the frontend I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

I fetch in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/rfx/all")
  .then(response => response.data)
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({ listrfx : data })
  })
}
```

REndering:

```
{
  this.state.listrfx.map(listrfx => (
     <tr key={listrfx.id}>  
       <th scope="row">{listrfx.id}</th>
       <td>{listrfx.code.id}</td>

   ))
}
```

`code.id` is foreign key in database and this is the type object please what I should to do

Comment: How do you currently handle rendering before the state is updated?

Comment: What's the output of `http://localhost:8080/rfx/all` ?

Comment: It might not be related to the issue but probably it would be better naming for the function variable inside `.map()` like `(e) => {}` and not the same name as the array itself.

Comment: What is an response of http://localhost:8080/rfx/all or what data you are getting inside listrfx

Comment: This usually means that "id" is not an available key inside the "listrfx" object or that the whole object is undefined. 
I will suggest you to try a console.log() of the object results from the APi call and see if the returning object is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The render looks good to me, I think the problem is that your component is rendering without waiting for your erquest response.

What about using async/await?

Like so

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const {data} = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/rfx/all");
  this.setState({ listrfx : data })
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Because that blocks the UX.